# Задача на объекты

Tags: javascript, объекты, инспекция-кода

Дайте отзыв по моему решению задачи на Объекты и методы (this). Что нужно исправить или усовершенствовать?

Попробуйте создать новый объект кошки со свойствами и добавьте два несколько методов:

- метод сна (кошка спит, если сыта)
- метод кушать (метод принимаем параметр количество каллорий еды)
- после каждого сна кошка теряет 100 едениц еды (каллорий)
                        Моё решение

```
let cat = {
  sleep: true,
  eating: 0,

  sleeping: function() {
    if(this.eating>0){
      this.sleep=true;
      alert('Кошка спит');
      this.eating=this.eating-100;
    } else {
      alert('Кошке нужно покушать');
    }
  }
}
sleeping(300);
```

Comment: интересно, как вы будете заводить вторую кошку. Клонированием?

Comment: @Арт'м Калачев Из очевидного - это `cat.sleeping(300);` и используя `this`, у Вас всегда будет `eating = 0`; То-есть кошка всегда будет голодная. Вы изначально хотите передать в функцию сытость кошки?

Comment: @Denis640Kb да, точно, спасибо за ответ, я забыл поставить название обьекта перед sleeping, а так же убрал this чтоб eating не равнялся 0, а был равен значению которое я введу в функцию.

Comment: @Арт'мКалачев Сейчас до компа доберусь и добавлю своё видение )))

Answer (score -1, accepted):

У вас кошка никогда не просыпается. и метода `кушать` я не вижу.

Что это такое

> ```js
>  sleeping(300);
> ```

Я не понял. Если это попытка вызвать метод `cat.sleeping()`, так нужно указывать имя объекта. Да и сам метод у вас не принимает никаких параметров

Я бы делал так

```js
let cat = {
  energy: 0,
  eat: function(energy) {
    this.energy += energy - 0;
  },
  sleep: function() {
    if (this.energy >= 100) {
      this.energy -= 100;
      return true;
    } else
      return false;
  }
};

document.getElementById('eat').addEventListener('click', function() {
  cat.eat(document.getElementById('energy').value);
  console.log(cat.energy);
});

document.getElementById('sleep').addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (cat.sleep())
    console.log('Кошка спит');
  else
    console.log('Кошке нужно покушать');
});
```

```html
<input id="energy" type="number" value="100"/><input type="button" id="eat" value="Кормить"/><br/>
<input type="button" id="sleep" value="Спать"/><br/>
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, я  только недавно начал изучать js и не могу написать код такой сложности как ваш)

Comment: @Арт'мКалачев извините, а что в нем сложного?

Comment: не знаю некоторых значений, например: document.getElementById, .addEventListener